# USB Speaker Audio works flawlessly when booting from USB, audio playback starts to stutter immediately after install

Tags: 20.04, sound, usb, pulseaudio, speakers

I built a custom desktop (specs below) at the start of the year and as part of setting up the system, I decided to install a Linux distro alongside Win10 on a separate SSD. Having never used a Linux distro prior, I've had my share of frustrations when setting up Ubuntu 20.04.4, but overall I was enjoying the learning process and was starting to get the hang of it...

...that is, until I hit a road block that can't seem to figure out, regarding the audio output of my speakers (Logitech Z625 2.1): when the OS is booted from USB prior to install, there are no audio issues whatsoever, but **as soon as Ubuntu is installed**, audio playback through speakers becomes choppy and, thus, *pretty much broken*.

What's curious is that the playback from the DAC amp (FiiO Olympus 2) that I have connected to my PC (which utilizes DigiHub USB on Ubuntu; not plain USB audio like the speakers) **does not** suffer from the same issue. Both the speakers and the DAC also work completely fine under Win10, so I don't see it being a device dependent issue either.

Tried multiple reinstalls and troubleshooting guides to no effect, maybe you folks will be able to figure out what I'm missing; thank you kindly in advance.

PS: system specs
/ CPU - Intel Core i7-12700K 3.6 GHz 12-Core Processor
/ Motherboard - Asus ROG STRIX Z690-I GAMING WIFI Mini ITX LGA1700
/ RAM - Kingston FURY Beast 32GB DDR5-5200 CL40
/ Main Storage - two Samsung 980 Pro 1 TB M.2-2280 NVME SSD drives (one for Win10, one for Linux)
/ Extra Storage - two Samsung 870 Evo 1 TB 2.5" SSD drives (for the other purposes)
/ GPU - Sapphire Radeon RX 6800XT 16 GB NITRO+
/ PSU - Corsair SF 750 W 80+ SFX
/ OS - Win10 / Ubuntu 20.04
/ Speaker System - Logitech Z625 2.1
/ DAC - FiiO Olympus 2

Answer (score 1):

I've had choppy sounds using the two most recent kernel updates.
Kernel 5.13.0-35 is GOOD, no sound problems
Kernel 5.13.0-37 Choppy sound
Kernel 5.13.0-39 Choppy sound (same type)

It hard to describe a sound in words, but when I play music and for example there is a single continuous string sound playing, every half a second or so, there is a distortion/hiccup.
The timing of the distortion is very consistent and doesn't deviate